# Is it possible to change the display value the selected option in Angular?

Tags: angular, list

I have a list of filters like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIOOX.png)

I want to make it so when an option is selected, the display name of the selected option value changes [also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwci3.png)

Where the display name of **only** the selected option changes to "Filters ({selected filter})" instead of just "{selected filter}"

e.g.
options:
a
b
c

If "a" was selected then the display name would change to "Filters (a)"

This is code for the select options:

```
                <select
                id="mobile-filter"
                aria-labelledby="filter-label"
                #mobileFilter
                class="mobile-filter-dropwdown"
                (change)="mobileFilterSelect()"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedMobileFilter"
            >
                <optgroup label="{{ 'RESEARCH.RESOURCES.FILTERING.MOBILE.FILTER_OPTIONS' | translate }}">
                    <option value="" selected>
                        Filters ({{ 'RESEARCH.RESOURCES.FILTERING.MOBILE.DEFAULT_OPTION' | translate }})
                    </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let option of filterOptions" class="option" [value]="option">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="isNonLiteralFilter(option); else literalLabel">
                            {{ 'RESEARCH.RESOURCES.FILTERING.' + option + '.LABEL' | translate }}
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-template #literalLabel>{{ option }}</ng-template>
                    </option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, have tried appending the text via this.mobileFilter.nativeElement, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your wanted result by:

1. on change trigger the `mobileFilterSelect($event)`, get the event value and assign it to a `selectedOptionValue` variable
2. modify your option like so:

<opt

```
<option value="" selected>
    Filters ({{ 'RES EARCH.RESOURCES.FILTERING.MOBILE.DEFAULT_OPTION' | translate }})
</option>
<option *ngFor="let option of filterOptions" class="option" [value]="option">
    {{option.name === selectedOptionName ? 'Filters ' + option.name : option.name}}
</option>
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the response, with this solution wouldn't all the options have the appended "Filters"?

I only want the option selected to have it

Comment: Ok I have edited, I believe this should fit your case

Answer (score 0):

this.mobileFilter.nativeElement.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText = "whatever you want"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.